# Disable text input when user selects option

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I'm attempting to disable a text input box if a user selects a value in another select input dropdown. Basically, they can either choose from the list, or enter a value, not both.

I'm currently trying this snippet, which doesn't seem to be having any effect:

```
//If the #chooseOrg select box has a value, we disable the #enterOrg box
var chosen = $('#chooseOrg').find('select');
var enterInput = $('#enterOrg').find('input');
if (chosen.val()) {
     enterInput.prop('disabled', true);
}

//On the new listings pages, for producer/org select
//Disable the text box input if the user selects an org from the list
$('#chooseOrg').find('select').on('select2-selecting', function() {
     if ($(this).val()) {
          enterInput.prop('disabled', true);
     }   
});
//Re-enable the text input if they clear their selection
$('#chooseOrg').find('select').on('select2-removed', function() {
     $('#enterOrg').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

EDIT: Updated code for better syntax

Note that I have to use find(':input') because I'm interacting with fields nested in code generated by a plugin, so I can't give the fields themselves proper IDs.

Anybody see what I'm missing?

Comment: I think the problem is I'm not getting values from the select2 input properly, but I can't figure out the right way....

Answer (score 0):

First you can select the input without the colon such as `$('input')`. More importantly, you'll want to set things like `selected` or `disabled` using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. Here's your code with these changes.

```
//If the #chooseOrg select box has a value, we disable the #enterOrg box
var chosen = $('#chooseOrg').find('input');
var enterInput = $('#enterOrg').find('input');
if (chosen.val()) {
    enterInput.prop('disabled', true);
}

//On the new listings pages, for producer/org select
//Disable the text box input if the user selects an org from the list
$('#chooseOrg').find('input').on('select2-selecting', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        enterInput.prop('disabled', true);
    }   
});
//Re-enable the text input if they clear their selection
$('#chooseOrg').find('input').on('select2-removed', function() {
    $('#enterOrg').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks! It's still not working. Since one of the inputs is a select dropdown, is it still supposed to work with just 'input' or would I need to use 'select'?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Change that to `.find('select')`.

Comment: Thanks. Even with those changes, no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here is the working solution:

```
//Disable the text input box of the selection already has a value
$('#chooseOrg').ready(function() {
    var chosen = $(this).find('select').val();
    var enterInput = $('#enterOrg').find('input');
    if (chosen) {
        enterInput.attr('disabled', true);
    }   
});
//Disable the text box input if the user selects an org from the list
$('#chooseOrg').on('select2-selecting', function() {
    var chosen = $(this).val();
    var enterInput = $('#enterOrg').find('input');
    if (chosen !== null) {
        enterInput.attr('disabled', true);
    }   
});
//Re-enable the text box input if they clear their selection
$('#chooseOrg').on('select2-removed', function() {
    $('#enterOrg').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```